# ORA-08143(not a valid month)

Tags: oracle

I have a date column in a table which is varchar2(10).
I am fetching some data from the table using select query. It goes on like:

```
Select
    ......................... 
from
    .........
where
    ................
    and (to_date(masc_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') between 
    to_date('10-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('11-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy'))
```

The masc_date is the date column which is varchar2(10) and the date values in this column are in the format 'dd-mm-yyyy'.
When I execute the above query, I get ORA-08143: not a valid month.

However when I modify my above query as:

```
Select
    ......................... 
from
    .........
where
    ................
    and (to_date(masc_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') between 
    (select to_date('10-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual) and 
    (select to_date('11-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual))
```

The query works fine. I am not able to find the reason for this error since in my first query, the date value in all "to_date" is in the same format and a char value.

**Note:The nls language in my database is american and the date format is "dd-mon-rr"**

Comment: I take it that the undisclosed parts of your select and where do not contain any dates?

Comment: And the trouble begins here "The masc_date is the date column which is varchar2(10)". Date column should have DATE as their datatype. Now you're left with data cleanup. Rene's script is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do is to check if all your data is indeed in dd-mm-yyyy format. More often than not the data can not be trusted.

```
declare
  cursor c is select masc_date from table;
   l_date date;
begin
  for r in c loop
     begin
        l_date := to_date(r.masc_date,'dd-mm-yyyy');
     exception
       when others then
         -- print out date that is not in the form dd-mm-yyyy
         dbms_output.put_line(r.masc_date);
     end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Hi Rene! Thanks a lot for your help. The problem was in the data where some values were not proper and since it was the production data, I didn't even gave a thought to this point.

Comment: If the data is not checked sooner or later it will fill up with rubbish.